# bxslider how to not use border and shadow in one of two sliders?

Tags: css, bxslider

I am using two bxsliders in one page. Everything is working fine. But I don't want to use border in one of my sliders.

As I understood this is css for border:

/** THEME
===================================*/

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    border: solid #fff 5px;
    left: -5px;
    background: #fff;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

If I understood you need this:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport 
{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: `box-shadow: none;` rather than '0'